# aspdotnetstorefront xml custom file

Tags: sql, xml, aspdotnetstorefront

To whom it may concern:

I created an xml file called affiliateReport.xml.config. Its purpose is to pull orders that match an affiliate so that an affiliate may view their orders.  To test it I wanted the orders to be listed in the lat_account.aspx file for now.  Unforatunately at this time it will only show me orders for AffiliateID equal to 0.  Thus I know I'm hitting the database, and I know it it showing me the data but it won't show me the data based on the affiliateID of the affiliate login.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  These files are from AspDotNetStoreFront Multistore. My code is below.

**AffiliateReport.xml.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<package version="2.1" displayname="Affiliate Report" debug="false" includeentityhelper="true" allowengine="true">
<query name="AffiliateReport" rowElementName="AffiliateOrders">
<sql>
    <![CDATA[
            SELECT * from Orders with (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN Affiliate on Affiliate.AffiliateID = Orders.AffiliateID
            WHERE  Orders.AffiliateID = @affiliateID
        ]]>
</sql>
<queryparam paramname="@affiliateID" paramtype="runtime" requestparamname="AffiliateID" sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0" validationpattern="^\d{1,10}$" />
</query>
<PackageTransform>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aspdnsf="urn:aspdnsf" exclude-result-prefixes="aspdnsf">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="LocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/LocaleSetting" />
  <xsl:param name="WebConfigLocaleSetting" select="/root/Runtime/WebConfigLocaleSetting" />
  <xsl:param name="XmlPackageName" select="/root/System/XmlPackageName" />  
  <xsl:param name="AffiliateID" select="/root/Runtime/WebConfigLocaleSetting" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <table width="90%">
          <tr>
              <td>Order Number</td>
              <td width="10px"> </td>
              <td>Affiliate ID</td>
              <td width="10px"> </td>
              <td>Total</td>
          </tr>

              <xsl:for-each select="/root/AffiliateReport/AffiliateOrders">
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber" /></td>
                  <td> </td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="AffiliateID" /></td>
                  <td> </td>
                  <td>$<xsl:value-of select="OrderTotal" /></td>
              </tr>    
              </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</PackageTransform>
 </package>
```

**From lat_account.aspx line 313 I added the following code**

```
<asp:Literal ID="XmlPackage_AffiliateOrders" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" />
```

**From lat_account.aspx.cs line 168 I added the following code**

```
XmlPackage_AffiliateOrders.Text = AppLogic.RunXmlPackage ("affiliatereport.xml.config", base.GetParser, ThisCustomer, SkinID, String.Empty, String.Format("AffiliateID={0}", AffiliateID), true, true);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive you are passing the correct value for Affiliate Id? My guess is the variable is not correctly set. You should attempt to debug at that line where you are setting the id.

Alternatively, you could set it manually to a different valid affiliate id

`XmlPackage_AffiliateOrders.Text = AppLogic.RunXmlPackage ("affiliatereport.xml.config", base.GetParser, ThisCustomer, SkinID, String.Empty, String.Format("AffiliateID={0}", 5), true, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of lat_account.aspx:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/XmlPackageControl.ascx" TagName="XmlPackage" TagPrefix="adnsf" %>
```

Add this to lat_account.aspx where you want your XmlPackage to render:

```
<adnsf:XmlPackage runat="server" PackageName="AffiliateReport.xml.config" ID="AffiliateReportPackage" />
```

Add this to the Page_Load method of lat_account.aspx.cd after the lines where the AffiliateID variable has been populated:

```
AffiliateReportPackage.RuntimeParams = string.Format("LoggedInAffiliateID={0}", AffiliateID);
```

Change your xmlpackage sql parameter to this:

```
<queryparam paramname="@affiliateID" paramtype="runtime" requestparamname="LoggedInAffiliateID" sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0" validationpattern="" />
```